# passing a vector<string>::iterator

Tags: c++, vector, iterator

I have a variable f declared as a vector::iterator and I have it pointed to a c_str() because I am trying to read files from a directory . The code complied at first but none of my functions were begin called. Show can I write my class and function to allow me to pass it and use it in another function:
This is part of the code in int main().

```
int main() {
    vector<string> files;

    if (d) {
        //we successfully opened the directory
        //while there's still something we haven't looked at
        while ((dir = readdir(d)) != NULL) {
            //get the name of that thing
            string filename = dir->d_name;
            //filter out what we don't want
            if (filename == "." ||             //filter out current dir
                    filename == ".." ||            //filter out parent dir
                    filename.find(".csv") == string::npos)   //here is where you set up the match
                continue;

            //and add what we do want to our files data structure
            files.push_back(basepath + "/" + filename);
        } 
    }

    map<string, int> foo;

    double fail = 0;

    for (vector<string>::iterator f = files.begin(); f != files.end(); ++f) {
        Extract_Organize process;
        cout << "What";
        process.transform();
        process.create_file();
        cout << "Finished!\n";
    }
    return 0;
}

class Extract_Organize {
    public:
        Extract_Organize; 
        void transform();
        void create_file();
        string double_integrate(int, int); 
};
#endif
```

Comment: Could you please format the C++ code? The indentation is all wrong.

Comment: Very bad formating.... Learn to format your code, before learning programming. After all, formatting is much easier than programming.

Comment: If you want to edit the question, don't roll back the proper formatting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing the problem is:

```
Extract_Organize process();
```

when it should be

```
Extract_Organize process;
```

There are *tons* of questions about **most vexing parse** here on StackOverflow, but the bottom line is that your code declares a function called `process` instead of creating an object `Extract_Organize`.

Comment: Yea but I guess I didn't state the question clear enough sorry about that. I am trying to pass f which is a vector<string>::iterator type to my functions and constructor but when I do so my program doesn't compile them.

Comment: @user1159808 please use ideone.com to post code that exibits the problem, stripping all other errors.

Comment: @user1159808 that's fine, but it doesn't give the compiler error you said you get.

Comment: I would hope the calls to process.transform() would fail to compile.

Comment: @bdow 1. did you make the change from my answer? From the code you posted, you did not. 2. ideone doesn't show an error.

Comment: I was referring to the original question, where he said it compiled.

Comment: Yeah that was up there from a previous edit I see but I changed it.